# After Submitting Comment Form Shows an Empy Page in WordPress

Tags: comments, forms

1. I have created comment form and write comments then submit. But it will shows an empty page.
2. The page path is http://localhost/isite/test/src/wp-comments-post.php
3. I have changed define(wp-debug true).
4. Rename the plugins, themes, htaccess, folder but no effect.
5. I have coded error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1); in config file .

   Could any one fix this problem....